# Attempting to ping RPC endpoint 6001 (Exchange Information Store)

Tags: exchange, migration, exchange-2003, rpc

I have Exchange 2003 running on a Windows Server 2003 box.
I am trying to use Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer which is failing with an error while attempting to ping RPC endpoint 6001 (Exchange Information Store)

I can see that many people have had the same issue, and I have tried the following advice to no avail: (see http://www.systemadminthings.com/2013/03/outlook-anywhere-rpc-over-http-failing.html)

1. Checking the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Rpcproxy\ValidPorts
2. Adding host entries to the C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc file - see although in my case the NetBIOS Name of Exchange Server and the FQDN name seem to be identical

> Testing RPC/HTTP connectivity.  The RPC/HTTP test failed.  Additional
>   Details  Elapsed Time: 5670 ms.
>
> Test Steps  Attempting to resolve the host name owa.mycompany.com in
>   DNS.  The host name resolved successfully.  Additional Details  IP
>   addresses returned: 199.203.XXX.XXX Elapsed Time: 15 ms.
>
> Testing TCP port 443 on host owa.mycompany.com to ensure it's
>   listening and open.  The port was opened successfully.  Additional
>   Details  Elapsed Time: 197 ms.
>
> Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.  The certificate
>   passed all validation requirements.  Additional Details  Elapsed Time:
>   651 ms.
>
> Test Steps  The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to
>   obtain the SSL certificate from remote server owa.mycompany.com on
>   port 443.  The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer successfully obtained
>   the remote SSL certificate.  Additional Details  Remote Certificate
>   Subject: CN=owa.mycompany.com, OU=Domain Control Validated -
>   RapidSSL(R), OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13,
>   ..... Elapsed Time: 583 ms.
>
> Validating the certificate name.  The certificate name was validated
>   successfully.  Additional Details  Host name owa.mycompany.com was
>   found in the Certificate Subject Common name. Elapsed Time: 0 ms.
>
> Certificate trust is being validated.  The certificate is trusted and
>   all certificates are present in the chain.  Test Steps  The Microsoft
>   Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to build certificate chains for
>   certificate CN=owa.mycompany.com, OU=Domain Control Validated -
>   RapidSSL(R), OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13,
>   ....  One or
>   more certificate chains were constructed successfully.  Additional
>   Details  A total of 1 chains were built. The highest quality chain
>   ends in root certificate CN=GeoTrust Global CA, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US.
>   Elapsed Time: 33 ms.
>
> Analyzing the certificate chains for compatibility problems with
>   versions of Windows.  Potential compatibility problems were identified
>   with some versions of Windows.  Additional Details  The Microsoft
>   Connectivity Analyzer can only validate the certificate chain using
>   the Root Certificate Update functionality from Windows Update. Your
>   certificate may not be trusted on Windows if the "Update Root
>   Certificates" feature isn't enabled. Elapsed Time: 3 ms.
>
> Testing the certificate date to confirm the certificate is valid. 
>   Date validation passed. The certificate hasn't expired.  Additional
>   Details  The certificate is valid. NotBefore = 7/23/2013 3:25:57 AM,
>   NotAfter = 9/24/2014 1:35:21 AM Elapsed Time: 0 ms.
>
> Checking the IIS configuration for client certificate authentication. 
>   Client certificate authentication wasn't detected.  Additional Details
>   Accept/Require Client Certificates isn't configured. Elapsed Time: 779
>   ms.
>
> Testing HTTP Authentication Methods for URL
>   https://owa.mycompany.com/rpc/rpcproxy.dll?mail.mycompany.com:6002. 
>   The HTTP authentication methods are correct.  Additional Details  The
>   Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer found all expected authentication
>   methods and no disallowed methods. Methods found: Basic Elapsed Time:
>   565 ms.
>
> Testing SSL mutual authentication with the RPC proxy server.  Mutual
>   authentication was verified successfully.  Additional Details 
>   Certificate common name owa.mycompany.com matches
>   msstd:owa.mycompany.com. Elapsed Time: 0 ms.
>
> Attempting to ping RPC proxy owa.mycompany.com.  RPC Proxy was pinged
>   successfully.  Additional Details  Completed with HTTP status 200 - OK
>   Elapsed Time: 182 ms.
>
> Attempting to ping RPC endpoint 6001 (Exchange Information Store) on
>   server mail.mycompany.com.  The attempt to ping the endpoint failed.
>   Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it  Additional
>   Details  The RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error (0x6ba) was thrown by the
>   RPC Runtime process. Elapsed Time: 3279 ms.

Comment: Did you install the "RPC over HTTP Proxy" Windows Feature on the server?  Did you enable basic authentication for the RPC virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: Hi techie007. I don't think 'RPC over HTTP Proxy' is relevant for me because I am running Exchange 2003/Windows Server 2003. (According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776122(v=exchg.141).aspx this is only relevant for Exchange 2010) With regard to your second comment, basic authentication was indeed enabled. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833401

Comment: RPC over HTTP proxy was already installed (Windows components/Networking Services). Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what the problem was. (I saw a similar problem on http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_27654858.html)

When I was manually specifying the server settings, I did not put in the *internal* host name for the Exchange Server

(I had also not applied all Windows Updates. I am not sure if this made a difference)